# GooglePlay Alert For Location Background Access

Tags: android, google-play

Google Recently Deleted my app because of new rules for location privacy.
I am using Mapbox library for maps and I have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, When I Upload new generated app to google play it says my app use background location and force me to the privacy tab for more information,
i dont have any `BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission and doesn't use this feature , and all of my usages is for selecting user current location via map.

Still, google says I use background location.
BTW :
use this code to remove permission even it does not exists :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

and still having problems.
what should I do?
I don't need background location permission and don't use it.

Comment: Maybe you are using a library that has it and this permission ends up in the merged manifest?

Comment: i use node:remove as i mentioned to remove from any library if use it

Comment: Any update on this? my app is getting deleted too. I don't think tools:node="remove" actually does anything

Comment: unfortunatly no , google decides very very rare about this , i removed mapbox from my project and its get fixed . map wasnt crucial part in my app

Comment: @Ali How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Merge Manifest tab in Android Studio to know the origin of permission.

refer to: [Manage manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#merge-manifests)

Most probably that Mapbox asking for this permission and you should exclude a feature to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
My flutter app has 2 **AndroidManifest.xml** files:

- profile/AndroidManifest.xml
- main/AndroidManifest.xml

When I added permission removal to the **profile/AndroidManifest.xml**, nothing has changed. But after extending the **main/AndroidManifest.xml** file, Google Play Console stooped showing the ERROR and I was able to publish my app with Mapbox component again.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="...">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).